# Thermal Expansion of Pump Shaft

Tags: thermal-field-theory

To determine the thermal expansion of a pump shaft the following formula is available:

$\Delta$L=$\alpha$L<sub>0</sub>$\Delta$T

Below I also have a sketch of the situation:

[image]

The shaft is constrained at the thick black line, so the shaft can only expand to the right. Let's assume the thermal expansion coefficient is 15.3$\times$10<sup>(-6)</sup> /<sup>$\circ$</sup>K. Furthermore, L<sub>0</sub> = 319 mm en $\Delta$T = 80 K.

$\Delta$L = 15.3$\times$10<sup>(-6)</sup>$\times$319$\times$80 = 0.3905 mm

For a shaft that can move free at both ends this means the shaft will expand 0,19525 mm to both sides.

Can I just simply assume that with the shaft shown it expands the full 0,3905 mm to the right, since it can't expand to the left (with respect to the part of the shaft on the right side of the thick black line) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Thermal expansion is uniform assuming uniformity in the material and uniform temperature across the shaft.

So relative to the constraint you need to proportionally allocate the calculated expansion to each side of the shaft by the lengths of each end to the constraint - of course assuming that both ends are free to expand without further constraints.